# Is this sentence grammatically correct? How should I write it with a different beginning?

Tags: word-usage, word-order, sentence-structure

The situation was that Person A (she) implied something (probably that he was an idiot), via a look, that offended Person B (he). So, Person B turned away from her while huffing. The vibe was lighthearted.

So, I wanted to describe all that in a sentence, and ended up writing,

"Offended by the implication behind the stare, he huffed, turning away from her."

Can I use this? Should it be "implication" or "implications"? Should I use " her stare" instead of "the stare"?

And if the sentence had to start with " Taking offense... " how would it be written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're better off saying "turned away in a huff" than "huffed, turning away from her."  The implication of "petty annoyance" isn't conveyed by your usage, which simply means he blew out some air.  ("I'll huff and I'll puff and I'll blow your house down," to quote the Big Bad Wolf in "The Three Little Pigs.")

You might consider this:

> Offended by the implication behind her stare, he turned away from her in a huff.

To change the beginning, you would say this:

> Taking offense at the implication...

I would use the singular *implication* unless there is more than one implication behind her stare.  There doesn't appear to be, but you know better than we do.

I would personally say *her* stare rather than *the* stare, although either is fine (as I understand it, you have already explained that person A has stared at person B elsewhere).

Now, you can use the "huff" as a verb to convey annoyance by context, usually along with quoted speech:

> "I'm finding the implication behind your stare rather offensive", he huffed.

Finally, none of this has a "lighthearted vibe."  If you want to create that, you'll have to put it in some sort of context of good-natured back-and-forth ribbing.

Comment: Ah, I see. This makes so much more sense! Thank you for explaining it so clearly too! And yes, I did actually. I liked the quoted speech one, though I'm sure he won't say that to his mentor's face... Haha. I'll probably use it somewhere else. Oh, it doesn't? Maybe it'll be funny if I write down the whole conversation. Well, I can hope! Thanks again, and have a good day! ^^